# How can i start a Docker-Compose.yml file

Tags: ubuntu, docker

How can I start Docker YML file. I have a project on Node js, and i do not know how to run a finished docker file. My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 desktop.

Comment: you mean Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml fie?

Comment: Show what in your file

Comment: Your Question is not clear, please edit your question so anybody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can start a docker-compose.yml File with this command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

You can build a Image from a Dockerfile with this command:

```
docker build -t "name:tag" .
```

And than run the image with:

```
docker run -d name:tag
```